# how to animate width with framer motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have the following `AdminSidebar` component:

```
export const AdminSidebar = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  const grid = expanded ? 'grid-cols-[auto_1fr_auto]' : 'grid-cols-[1fr_auto]';

  return (
    <motion.div
      className='sticky right-0 top-[100px] my-4 block h-fit shrink-0 overflow-hidden rounded-l-[4px] border-[1.5px] border-r-0 border-border bg-card shadow-md'
    >
      <div
        id='admin-bar'
        className={cn('right-0 top-[150px] flex flex-col items-start p-[4px] ')}
      >
        <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
          <Button className='p-2' onClick={handleClick} variant='ghost'>
            {expanded ? <PanelRightClose /> : <PanelRightOpen />}
          </Button>
          {expanded && <p className='font-bold'>Skróty</p>}
        </div>
        <Separator className='mb-2' />

        {...items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <TooltipProvider>
              <Tooltip delayDuration={200}>
                <TooltipTrigger asChild>
                  <Link
                    href={item.href}
                    className='block w-full rounded-sm p-2 py-4 hover:bg-muted'
                  >
                    <div className={`grid ${grid} items-center gap-2`}>
                      {item.icon}
                      {expanded && item.label}
                      {item.count ? (
                        <Badge variant='default'>{item.count}</Badge>
                      ) : (
                        <div></div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                </TooltipTrigger>
                <TooltipContent side='left'>{item.label}</TooltipContent>
              </Tooltip>
            </TooltipProvider>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

So the number of columns changes depending on `expanded` state and hence the total width changes. Unfortunately, for now there is no animation when expanding. How can I add that? I tried to add:

```
animate={{ width: expanded ? '200px' : '75px' }} // works
```

and it works but I don't want to add `width` size manually and make it automatic. How can I do that?